# The maximum of $|\frac{1}{z^2+1}|$ when $z \in C[0,r]$

Tags: complex-analysis

The maximum of $|\frac{1}{z^2+1}|$ when $z \in C[0,r]$

My thinking:

Parametrize the curve $C[0,r]$ so that $z = re^{it}, 0\leq t \leq 2\pi$. Then $|\frac{1}{z^2+1}|=|\frac{1}{r^2e^{2it}+1}|$. Then I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximizing $|\frac{1}{r^2e^{2it}+1}|$ is the same as minimizing the denominator $|r^2e^{2it}+1|$ which happens precisely when $r^2e^{2it}$ and $1$ are in totally opposite directions, i.e. $r^2e^{2it}$ has argument $\pi$, so $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

So the maximum of $|\frac{1}{r^2e^{2it}+1}|$ happens when $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and its value is  $\frac{1}{1-r^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

By writing $|r^2-1|=||r^2e^{2it}|-|1||\leqslant|r^2e^{2it}+1|\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{|r^2e^{2it}+1|}\leqslant\frac{1}{|r^2-1|} $ and $\frac{1}{|r^2-1|}$ is obtained when $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$.